# is it possible to use same memory buffers for different kernels in OpenCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I am implementing a kernel function in which the memory from the host side is transferred to kernel.The kernel has three functions.. Is it possible to share the same memory buffers with the kernels at different times ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple kernels can use the same memory objects, as long as there is no risk for the kernels to be executed at the same time.  It is the case for the usual "single command queue not created with out of order execution".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this with my ray tracer.  I have three kernels.  A preprocessor which changes geometry, a ray tracer , and a post processor which does image processing.  I share memory buffers with all three of them.  I make sure the kernels finish before I start the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You can share memory without any problem. If the memory is read only you can even use that memory object as an input for 2 kernels running concurrently (ie: different GPUs/same context).

However, if you want to overwrite the memory zones, then be careful and use events to sync your kernels. I strongly recomend the events mechanism, since it enables parallel I/O read and writes to the memory zones in another queue.